# laravel 5.2 ->update not works

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

in my controller i have `$data['column1'] = 1;` It updates database with `$x->update($data);`
Why if add `$data['column2'] = 2;` it ignores second parameter? I checked with `dd($data);` and it shows both parameters.
I removed default value, which being inserted by mysql, but that did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that **column2** is listed in the **$fillable** property of your model. Only attributes that are listed there can get a value assigned with your model's **create/update** methods.